# CSS make different level divs.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a website that essentially makes boxes, you can click on the box, and it will expand, if you click again on the box, it was return to original size. This is done via:

```
$container.on(
  "click",
  ".resultLike",
  function(event){
    $('.resultLike').html("liked");
  }
);
```

No, there's a div inside that box called `resultLike`, and when you click it, it also calls a function, but the issue is that the box closes.  I'm wondering if there's some css magic I can do to alter this.

I tried setting the `z-index` to a number higher than the box.  No avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a [non]-working example on JSFiddle? Not really sure I understand the issue.

Comment: The code you show us don't expand the box...

Comment: Sorry, I'll get on a js fiddle, I was just talking about generic things, but I'll do the fiddle, one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation with `e.stopPropagation()`: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/MVNTW/1/

Comment: This is precisely what it was!  Thank you very much!